# Dealing with variable height items in MvxListView

Tags: android-listview, mvvmcross

I am using the MvxListView with items that have variable height. **The ItemTemplate is dependant on the data item so we use an MvxAdapter and return the relevant View from GetBindableView.**

On first load of the View the ListView is the correct height but if I rebuild the underlying ItemSource the height of the ListView is too short meaning I need to scroll to see the last item.

This happens even if the Items in the ItemSource are the same.

There is no issue if I ensure all child views are the same height.

The ListView layout is

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- Some Text Views-->
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/pale_blue"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
            android:prompt="@string/encounter_location_prompt"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lstEntries"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Entries"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The layout of one of the item views that does not get properly measured is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:background="@drawable/customborder2">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            local:MvxBind="Text Description"
            android:text="term"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            local:MvxBind="Text Instructions"
            android:text="Instructions" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="SomeText"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:textColor="@color/deep_blue" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I understand this is an issue with the underlying Android ListView but I wanted to know if there was an accepted MVVMCross solution. Do I inherit from MvxListView and force a re measure on each child view?

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the layout code?

Comment: Done. I have also added a key piece of info, the use of MvxAdapter to choose a template at runtime

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` at every level - is this layout itself embedded inside a scrolling view? If it is, then maybe use `MvxLinearLayout` instead of `MvxListView` - but do understand that this will be less resource efficient for long lists...

Comment: :-) yes it is within a scrollingview and in fact I am in the process of tidying up a different View and switching out multiple ListView for MvxLinearLayout. I didn't find MvxLinearLayout until this morning. The resource efficiency issue is because of the Views no longer being virtualized I assume. I will look at switching to MvxLinearLayout on the View too

Comment: I changed the height of the MxListView to match_parent and that has stopped the problem. I assume it is my relative lack of experience with Android layout that causes me to think that makes no sense. If I ask it to wrap_content why does it work initially then with the same list of data items does it no longer completely wrap_content?